# Declare var in other macro to be used in a different macro for DBT

Tags: sql, macros, jinja2, dbt

The main idea is to have a constant variable and then have the possibility to use it in other parts of the code or macros for DBT.

Example of a macro that contains constants:

```
{% macro constant_vars() -%}
    
{%
set var_1 = {
 "0": ["0"],
 "1": ["1", "11", "111"]
}
%}

{%
set var_2 = {
 "2": ["2"],
 "3": ["3"]
}
%}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

Macro that use a constant from the previous macro:

```
{% macro evaluate(
    column_to_check
) -%}

CASE
    {% for map_key in var_1 -%}
    WHEN ({{column_to_check}} IN UNNEST( {{ var_1[map_key] }})) THEN
        '{{ map_key }}'
    {% endfor -%}
    ELSE
        "-1"
END
{%- endmacro -%}
```

SQL sentence created for DBT:

```
SELECT 
[..]
  evaluate(column1)
[..]
FROM
 table
```

DBT compiled query:

```
SELECT 
[..]
CASE
    WHEN (column1 IN UNNEST(["0"])) THEN
        '0'
    WHEN (column1 IN UNNEST(["1", "11", "111"])) THEN
        '1'
    
    ELSE
        "-1"
END
[..]
FROM
 table
```

Is it possible? Exist another way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an issue of scope of variable. Your variable defined in` constant_vars` are only visible inside this macro.

Comment: Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε. How can make it visible? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables you declare using `{% set my_var = ... %}` are local in scope, meaning that they won't be declared in any contexts outside of where you set them.

dbt also supports a `var` macro, which can act as global variables. [Docs for var](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/var)

You set `var` in your `dbt_project.yml` file like this:

```yaml
vars:
  var_1:
    0: ["0"]
    1: ["1", "11", "111"]
```

and then access the values using `{{ var('var_1') }}`.

Another option is to *return* the variable(s) from the macro. This would work well if the values are not static/literals:

```sql
-- in macros/get_var_1.sql
{% macro get_var_1() %}
{% set var_1 = {
    "0": ["0"],
    "1": ["1", "11", "111"]
} %}
{{ return(var_1) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then you can call the macro and assign it to a variable in your model:

```sql
-- in models/my_model.sql
{% set my_var = get_var_1() %}
```

Comment: Really interesting answer. I will check. Thank you!

Comment: I had to change this to {{ return(var_1) }} but other than that worked as needed. Thank you!

Comment: my mistake! answer has been updated